# Electron: Drag and Drop a file on the icon

Tags: windows, macos, drag-and-drop, electron

With an Electron app, is it possible to open a file by dragging it on the application icon, as with a normal desktop application?

Using code from elsewhere, I can open a file which has been dragged onto the document window:

```
document.ondragover = document.ondrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
};

document.body.ondrop = (event) => {
    openFile(event.dataTransfer.files[0].path.toString());
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

I would like to be able to open the file by dragging it on the application icon itself.

In some cases, that would also mean starting the application if it isn’t already running.

Comment: Do you mean drag it on the desktop icon? The dragged file's path will be included as an argument that you should handle via `process.argv`.

Comment: @hijleh How do you respond to that if the application is already running?

Comment: Check my answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

The dragged file's path will be passed as a command line argument. You can access command line arguments using [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

```js
const { app } = require('electron')

// You can get the dragged file's path like this
if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
    const filePath = process.argv[1]
    handleFile(filePath)
}

// If you only allow a single instance of your application to be running
// you should use the 'second-instance' event to handle the case if your app is already running
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, argv, workingDirectory) => {
      // Someone tried to run a second instance
      // Handle argv here
      if (argv.length >= 2) {
          const filePath = argv[1]
          handleFile(filePath)
      }
  })
}

function handleFile(filePath) {
 // handle the file as you want
}
```

Comment: 1. The `argv` parameter is very broken, and the official workaround is to pass arguments through `additionalData` in `requestSingleInstanceLock`, which comes after `workingDirectory` in the event handler. (`additionalData` is also buggy.)
2. You should use `path.resolve(workingDirectory, filePath)` to account for file paths relative to the second instance's working directory.
3. When the app is is packaged, `process.argv` looks different than in development. Use `const argsArray = process.argv.slice(app.isPackaged ? 1 : 2);`
4. Note that `app.quit()` doesn't immediately exit the process.